# Switching GPUImageFilter chain on the fly

Tags: gpuimage

I'm running a set of filters on a video stream (not using `GPUImageVideoCamera`, but processing a sample buffer) currently using `GPUImageFilterPipeline`.

To change my filters, I'm simply using:

```
[self.filterPipeline replaceAllFilters:self.warmFilterArray];
```

Or         `[self.filterPipeline replaceAllFilters:self.coolFilterArray];`

Or         `[self.filterPipeline removeAllFilters];`

I'm having a problem with crashes whenever I change filters. The crashes are inconsistent, but if I change filters too rapidly, I'm more likely to crash.

I suspect that it has something to do with the targets in the filter chain being abruptly removed. Any ideas on how to safely remove filters? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using multiple pipelines with multiple inputs. I send the sample buffer to be processed to whichever input is appropriate, allowing me to avoid removing filters from a chain while it is processing!